# What difference does it make if many differential equations can't be solved analytically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, soft-question

Calculus invention happened only few hundred years ago. So I assume that differential equations are being discovered and solved since that time. When I was in school I learnt that most differential equations cannot be solved analytically and are thus solved using numerical methods.

The question in my mind is, what difference does it make if we can't solve a differential equation analytically? Is that bad? Are people doing research to find analytical solutions to old differential equations? Also, before computers existed, were people still able to use numerical methods to solve differential equations numerically? That would be quite a lot of work.

Comment: Numerical solutions are slow.  Nothing wrong with them, but it's expensive (however measured) to work that way.

Comment: There are analytical methods to study differential equations and their behaviour without requiring to know the exact solution. Two of the many that I know are widespread are [phase space analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) and [Lyapunov exponents analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent). Also some specific differential equations widely used in physics had their own analysis methods like the [Sturm–Liouville equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory), as an example of analysis when the exact solution is not known.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I was in school I learnt that most differential equations cannot be solved analytically and are thus solved using numerical methods.

Perhaps it would be more accurate to say that numerical methods is one of the two major responses humanity came up with to the issue of not being able to write exact solutions to differential equations. The other response is the so-called qualitative approach: according to this approach the specifics of the solution itself is not essential; since e.g. even if one could solve an ODE exactly, it is highly unlikely that from a more anthropocentric point of view all the numbers will be known with complete resolution. Both of these methods started gaining momentum roughly at the end of the 19th century; and in contemporary research they are related in subtle ways.

> The question in my mind is, what difference does it make if we can't solve a differential equation analytically? Is that bad?

Let us consider ODEs for simplicity. One can think of an ODE as an infinitesimal expression of the law of evolution of some dynamical system: an ODE literally describes the change that occurs in an "infinitesimal amount of time". Having instead the "solution" provides information that is global in time: it describes the change that occurs in some finite amount of time.

Having exact solutions (or from the qualitative or numerical point of view, approximate solutions) allows one to for instance visualize the time evolution of the system. Certainly without the solution one can visualize the ODE itself by considering the slope field or the vector field etc.., but arguably the graph of a function is more concrete than the graph of its derivative.

> Are people doing research to find analytical solutions to old differential equations?

(I am not quite an expert in differential equations, but I work in a field called dynamics, which is in a certain sense one of the modern, qualitative reincarnations of (mostly ordinary) differential equations; thus my perspective as a dynamicist could be relevant.)

There is certainly still a lot of interest in exact solutions; mostly in fields where there is a lot of interface with engineering and other sciences that use mathematics. On the other hand from a more internal point of view, the issues of existence and uniqueness seem to be central. Beyond existence and uniqueness, from the qualitative point of view one is interested in understanding e.g. the shapes of the trajectories, how the trajectories entangle with each other (if at all), whether the differential equation has sensitive dependence on initial conditions, whether the DE can be simplified using a change of coordinates, whether a more rough time evolution can be similarly represented via a change of coordinates by a DE, ... . Whereas from the numerical point of view one is interested in e.g. whether a certain class of numerical methods approximate well solutions of a certain class of DEs (as far as I understand).

> Also, before computers existed, were people still able to use numerical methods to solve differential equations numerically? That would be quite a lot of work.

Indeed, the Euler method goes roughly back to the 18th century (Euler was a student of Bernoulli, a contemporary of Leibniz, so as a heuristic one can think of Euler as "second generation"). The Runge-Kutta methods, of which the Euler method is a specific case, go roughly back to the end of 19th century. As I understand this family of methods is still highly acclaimed in numerical methods, and they predate the invention of computers.

It is not unreasonable to speculate that Euler did use his method; for graphs one draws by hand the major drawbacks of the Euler method commonly recognized in our times would not be the main bottleneck in terms of work complexity.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to differential equations, especially PDEs, I disagree with the first comment above. The analytical solutions that involve infinite sums and large exponentials, etc., are sometimes even worthless for actually computing the answer to visualize. Numerical solutions are often far easier and actually better suited for computation.

But numerical methods have drawbacks. One is that ideally you want to prove their correctness, and what might seem like a good numerical method at first could prove to give really wrong answers or introduce non-real oscillations or other errors over time. This is really the use of analytical solutions, proving that the numerical methods are stable and accurate.

For example, here are some papers I was reading where the authors developed both a [numerical](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2013/384246/) and [analytical](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Wenchao-Liu-2/publication/256718186_Numerical_Solution_of_a_Moving_Boundary_Problem_of_One-Dimensional_Flow_in_Semi-Infinite_Long_Porous_Media_with_Threshold_Pressure_Gradient/links/58007c9e08ae32ca2f5dc3a7/Numerical-Solution-of-a-Moving-Boundary-Problem-of-One-Dimensional-Flow-in-Semi-Infinite-Long-Porous-Media-with-Threshold-Pressure-Gradient.pdf) approach to the same problem. The analytical result proved the numerical result, but it looks like way more work to get the analytical one, and they even remark so in their paper,

> however, little research
> has been found on the exact analytical solutions of relevant mov-
> ing boundary models of the flow in porous media with threshold
> pressure gradient. The research on the exact analytical solutions
> is very necessary because it can help to strictly verify the correct-
> ness of existent approximate analytical solutions and numerical
> solutions, and validate the pore-scale network modeling for the
> flow in porous media with threshold pressure gradient.

> And through the similarity transformation method,
> the exact analytical solutions of the moving boundary problems
> are obtained, which can be used for the verification of approximate
> analytical solutions and numerical solutions and the validation of
> pore-scale network modeling for the flow in porous media with
> threshold pressure gradient.

If the analytical solutions were so great, why wouldn't the authors just use them? It's also likely that one would want to adapt the numerical method to a slightly modified problem that can't be solved analytically, where one perhaps hopes the numerical method is still correct, but I'm not an expert in that. I use numerical methods and see if it matches my data: good enough for non-academic work, I guess.